# When use "exec 1>ok.log", how can I output the specified content to the screen within a shell script?

Tags: shell, stdout, exec

As follow, I only want the command `echo "this is to stdout"` output to my screen instead of to the file `ok.log`, how can I do?
I search for the usage of `exec` shell command, but without result, please advice me

```
[root@161 tmp]# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

[root@161 tmp]# cat 2.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>ok.log
exec 2>error.log
#exist dir
ls /home/
#no exist dir
ls /etca/
#to stdout
echo "this is to stdout"
#other cmds
...
```

Comment: If you remove `exec 1>ok.log`, the stdout will be shown on the screen.

Comment: As I said above, I only want this command `echo "this is to stdout"` shown on my screen, so `exec 1>ok.log` is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the original stdout to a temporary file descriptor before you redirect it. In this example I use file descriptor 3.

```
exec 3>&1
exec 1>ok.log
echo "This will go to ok.log"
echo "This will go to the original stdout" >&3
```

Comment: You're right, there is another way:`echo "this is to stdout" > /dev/tty`

Comment: That `/dev/tty` method is a little bit different and not ideal. It would give surprising results if the script was run with stdout already redirected somewhere else. For example, if you ran `./script.sh >/dev/null` you would be surprised to see output on the terminal. If you ran it as a cron job the output wouldn't be in the cron result email.

Comment: Thks, learned about